# Windows 2008 x64 displays SP1 when SP2 is installed

Tags: windows-server-2008

After setting up a Windows 2008 x64 server (not R2), I installed a number of Microsoft updates.  After installing these updates, the computer reports that it has SP1 installed, not SP2.

I believe the culprit is KB917607, which allows Windows 2008 to display .hlp files.

Now I have to upgrade Internet Explorer on this server, and it won't install without SP2.  I am very leery about reinstalling SP2, as I have installed a large number of post-SP2 updates, and I've had issues after reinstalling SP2 in similar circumstances.

How can I fix Windows so it reports the correct service pack?

**UPDATE:**  One more piece of information - if I go into the control panel app "Programs and Features" and click "Show Updates", update KB948465 is there.  That's SP2, but computer properties still show SP1.

Comment: `I've had issues after reinstalling SP2 in similar circumstances.` Is there's something incredibly unusual about your configuration? The situation you're in is uncommon. If you've experienced on other servers as well, there's probably something wrong with your base image.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the contents of `%windir%\system32\prodspec.ini` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` (specifically `BuildLab`, `CSDVersion`, `CurrentBuild`, `CurrentBuildNumber`, and `CurrentVersion`) match that of another unit with SP2 installed.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the registry. I compared this to another server, and all the keys are the same except for CSDVersion, which is "Service Pack 2" in the known-good server and "Service Pack 1" on the problem server.  Depite this, the other keys on the problem server indicate sp2, e.g. BuildLab value is "6002.vistasp2_gdr.110617-0336".

Comment: Unfortunately changing this value didn't fix the problem!  Crud...  Also see update to my question.

Comment: I'd reinstall SP2 then.  You may consider rebuilding the server if you suspect this will be less troublesome.